# How to use subquery as a geometry parameter on postgis?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, postgis

I need to compare some spatial data on postgis, but I need to compare with not geometry data in another table "card_history", witch contains lat and long fields necessary to use "ST_GeomFromText" function.
But how do I do it in a single query?
Since I'm working on php (witch is not relevant) it would be very painful to make a lot of queries...

I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere
  (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(
      (SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) long from card_history) 
      (SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) lat from card_history))',4326),
   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(17.0712215 48.15825)',4326)
  )
```

But the subquery doesn't seem to work as parameter for "POINT".
Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
WITH 
lon AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) AS long from card_history
), 

 lat AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) AS lat from card_history
)

SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText(

'POINT(' || lon.lon || ' ' || lat.lat || ',4326'),

ST_GeomFromText('POINT(17.0712215 48.15825)',4326))

FROM lon, lat;
```

Comment: Sintax error on or next to "AS", but if I remove will return the same sintax error as before: ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(("" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry

Comment: Got it, just posting here the query I could figure it out based on @zero323 answer.

WITH 
lon AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) long from card_history
), 

 lat AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) lat from card_history
)

SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText(
'POINT(' || lon.long || ' ' || lat.lat || ')'),

ST_GeomFromText('POINT(17.0712215 48.15825)'))

FROM lon, lat;

Comment: It is @grouch answer :)

Comment: there shouldn't be two distinct selections for lat/lon, it should be the same select otherwise it will be a outer join